# Angular 8 graphql.module localstorage.getItem not available

Tags: angular, authentication, graphql, apollo

Versions used:

Angular version: 8.3 
apollo-client: 2.6.0

I'm trying to use graphql with authorised jwt token. The token gets set in localstorage after login.

On login, the homepage gets loaded where a gql query is executed, however, token isn't available on load due to graphql.module.ts being imported on app load. Is there a way for this module to be modified? reference link is [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/recipes/authentication/)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApolloModule, Apollo, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLinkModule, HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';

const uri = '/graphql';

export function provideApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  const basic = setContext((operation, context) => ({
    headers: {
      Accept: 'charset=utf-8'
    }
  }));

  // Get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const auth = setContext((operation, context) => ({
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
  }));

  const link = ApolloLink.from([basic, auth, httpLink.create({ uri })]);
  const cache = new InMemoryCache();

  return {
    link,
    cache
  }
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ApolloModule,
    HttpLinkModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: provideApollo,
    deps: [HttpLink]
  }]
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

Comment: I have a setup very similar to yours.  Are you including your `GraphQLModule` in your imports array on app.module.ts?  That works for my situation and I'm able to inject my token for all subsequent calls after it has been set in my localstorage.

Comment: can you show the code you're using in your home page to call graphQL?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trimmed down version of a graphql call I'm making to a guarded endpoint that requires a valid JWT.  Obviously this logic should be put into a service class, but it will at least demonstrate how your home page should look to tie into your graphql module class and have it inject your JWT into the requests.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private apollo: Apollo
  ) { }
  user: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apollo.query<any>({
      query: gql`
        query users {
          loggedInUser {
            email,
            avatarUrl
          }
        }
      `
    }).subscribe(result => {
      this.user = result.data.loggedInUser;
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my graphql module which is very similar to yours except I have also included a refresh token strategy as well.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpLinkModule, HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication/services/authentication.service';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { Observable } from 'apollo-link';


export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink, authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {

  const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('auth_token')
      }
    });
    return forward(operation);
  });

  const errorLink = onError(({ forward, graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      if (graphQLErrors.some(x => x.message.toLowerCase() === 'unauthorized')) {
        return promiseToObservable(authenticationService.refreshToken().toPromise()).flatMap(() => forward(operation));
      }
    }
  });

  return {
    link: errorLink.concat(authLink.concat(httpLink.create({ uri: '/graphql' }))),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

const promiseToObservable = (promise: Promise<any>) =>
    new Observable((subscriber: any) => {
      promise.then(
        value => {
          if (subscriber.closed) {
            return;
          }
          subscriber.next(value);
          subscriber.complete();
        },
        err => subscriber.error(err)
      );
    });


@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink, AuthenticationService]
    }
  ]
})
export class GraphqlModule { }
```